# Convert Hiragino-Sans-GB-W3 to others font format

Tags: font-face, webfonts

I had this two fonts called

-Hiragino-Sans-GB-W3.otf (12.5mb)
-Hiragino-Sans-GB-W6.otf (12.6mb)

but I had try many font convertor, 
they didn't support it because the font size too big.
Is there any way to make it convert to others format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to strip all the unneeded characters and features from your font so its size get more manageable.

Of course, you have to be sure you’re legally allowed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried convert your font throught https://onlinefontconverter.com?

It has no size limit, but will fail if it takes longer than 30s to give a response after it has been completely uploaded. since its a big file, try to convert it to only 1 format at the time

Comment: [It appears](https://github.com/jimmywarting/ofc) you are affiliated with onlinefontconverter.com. Please note that our [self-promotion policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497) requires you to disclose this information in answers like this one.